# MVC3 Passing data from controller to another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewdata, viewbag

Passing small amount of data from one controller to another controller, do I use ViewBag? ViewData? or Session...etc... what is the right approach.

e.g. My First [Controller1]/[Action: Register] generates the userid and then needs to be redirected to another controller

> return RedirectToAction("Create", "Controller2");

Then on Create (HttpPost) I am storing the data + plus the userid to the database and then redirecting to the next controller which acts the same way on HttpPost it stores the data + plus the userid to the database.

I am a bit lost what approach should I take, how do I pass the userid in a secure way/right way?, please advice, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its not private, just pass it on the url using the third parameter in your redirect:
new {id=whateverValue}

If it is private data, use TempData - it will be removed after the next request reads it (well at the end of the request)

Comment: Thanks I want the id not to show in the url and TempData will not be available when calling controller #3, it will only be available on controller #2, How would I keep it throughout the process. Thanks,

Comment: thx, is there any other approach to pass data between controllers? except for TempData (since it is only available ones) and in the url-query?.

Comment: Sure the http cache (memory cache) database table etc

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can leverage route values to accomplish this. Here is an example:

```
return RedirectToAction("Create", "Controller2", new { userId = myVar });
```

For more information on route values, check out RouteValueDictionary http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.aspx